# Use R to calculate median without replicating elements

Tags: r, median, frequency-distribution, quartile

I have a frequency distribution with huge numbers. I want to calculate median and quartiles but R complains. Here is what is working for small numbers:

```
> TABLE <- data.frame(DATA = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19), F = c(48,0,192,1152,5664,23040,77952,214272,423984,558720,267840,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
> summary(rep(TABLE$DAT,TABLE$F))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   9.000  10.000   9.397  10.000  11.000
```

Here is, what I get for huge numbers:

```
> TABLE <- data.frame(DATA = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19), F = c(240,0,1200,9600,69600,470400,2992800,17859840,98312880,489292800,2164619760,8325820800,26865302400,68711068800,128967422400,153763315200,96770419200,26824089600,2395008000))
> summary(rep(TABLE$DAT,TABLE$F))
Error in rep(TABLE$DAT, TABLE$F) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In summary(rep(TABLE$DAT, TABLE$F)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

This error does not surprise me because using "rep" I wanted to create an enormous vector. But I do not know, how to avoid this and calculate the median and the quartiles.

Comment: Change the `TABLE$F` to `double` and try.

Comment: Trying to run that killed R!

Comment: @MKR: I am quite a beginner, can you please explain, how to change to double?

Comment: You can try `TABLE <- tibble::as_tibble(TABLE)`. I'm not sure if those will still be coerced to integer by `rep`. You can give it a try.

Comment: Can't test it as I don't have R at hand but have a look at ftp://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/pub/math/statlib/S/Harrell/help/Hmisc/html/wtd.stats.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to replicate that monster to use `summary()` you can get "weighted quantiles".
[This post has a formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13169/defining-quantiles-over-a-weighted-sample).
But as with most things, once you know the right terms you can find a package
that already does the work!

```r
#install.packages("Hmisc")

TABLE <- data.frame(DATA = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19), F = c(240,0,1200,9600,69600,470400,2992800,17859840,98312880,489292800,2164619760,8325820800,26865302400,68711068800,128967422400,153763315200,96770419200,26824089600,2395008000))


Hmisc::wtd.quantile(TABLE$DATA, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), weight = TABLE$F)
#> 25% 50% 75% 
#>  15  16  16
```

Created on 2018-04-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).